# How to do a 3D plot in matplotlib where two functions are evaluated with only one variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, 3d

All 3D plot examples I find are of the form X,Y = data and f(X,Y) is the plotted function. What I need is a 3D plot where X contains data points while Y = f(X) and Z = g(X) are displayed on the respective axes. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can set `x_points` on `DataFarme` then apply `function_y` and `function_z` on `DataFrame` then plot points like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def create_Y(x):
    return x**2 + 2*x - 10

def create_Z(x):
    return np.sin(x)


df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, num=500)})
df['Y'] = df['X'].apply(create_Y)
df['Z'] = df['X'].apply(create_Z)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
ax.plot(xs = df['X'], ys = df['Y'],zs = df['Z'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can I also add a projection of the graph to either the XZ or the XY plane? If so how do I integrate that projection into the graph?